# Ensure network shares are constantly mounted

Tags: mac, file-sharing, drobo, afp

I have a Drobo connected to my network that serves up media to two Macs. Essentially this server acts as a Timemachine and file server for large media files. The frustrating part is that I need to forcibly tell it to mount the shares every time I restart, not to mention how frustrating it is when shares disconnect and don't reconnect.

Is there some way can scan or monitor the two shares and ensure they are mounted at all times? Perhaps somehow check if they are mounted every 5 minutes and if they are not mounted, mount them?

Comment: you can probably write a script in batch centered around the 'net use' command. There is also AutoIt which has the _WinNet_OpenEnum command to enumerate existing connections on a client and _WinNet_RestoreConnection command to reconnect (and many other related functions as well)

Comment: I am on a Mac, I did mention that. :-)

Comment: Yes, I should be reading tags. In that case, similar idea, either with applescript if you insist on using AFP or bash if you want to use NFS (recommended - less bloat, stateless). You probably wouldn't even need to mess with bash if you set it up with NFS though, it would just work.